# Can I make a class that participates in "if let" constructs the way the Optional does?

Tags: swift, boolean, option-type

I can use `if let` construct to unwrap optionals, like this:

```
if let x = someOptional {
    // x represents the value of someOptional, and is known to be non-nil
}
```

In addition to doing the unwrapping, Swift compiler knows to treat the `let x = someOptional` construct as a logical value.

Is the logic for `Optional` built into the compiler itself, or is it possible to define my own class with the same behavior?

In other words, can I write something like this:

```
class MyLogical : SomeProtocolForSwiftToKnowHowToTreatMyClassAsBool {
    ...
    var boolValue : Bool {
        return ... // true or false, depending on the state of my object
    }
}
```

and have Swift treat it like a logical value that I can put inside an `if` condition, with or without `let`?

```
if let x = getMyLogical() {
    assert(x.boolValue) // boolValue must evaluate to true to get here
}
```

**Note:** I remember there being a `LogicalValue` protocol in an earlier version of Swift, and `Optional` used to conform to that protocol. `LogicalValue` is gone now, and there is no replacement (`BooleanType` has the `boolValue` property now, but Apple discourages conformance to the `BooleanType` protocol unless your class represents a simple Boolean value).

Comment: "and have Swift treat it like a logical value that I can put inside an if condition" But you seem to be confusing apples with oranges, no that now it isn't clear what you want to do. In `if let x = getMyLogical()`, `getMyLogical()` would need to yield something that can be `nil` and unwrapped if not — not a logical value at all. The "logic" in "if let" comes later. Do you want a Boolean-like thing or an Optional-like thing?

Comment: @matt Doesn't `NilLiteralConvertible` represent something to which I can set `nil`, not something that I can convert back to `nil`? I wouldn't mind returning `nil` for things that I want to keep outside my `if` statement, insead of returning `false`. Basically, I am looking for a way to "plug in" custom logic into the functionality of `if` statement - similar to the way I can do it in C++ by providing an implicit operator for converting to `bool`.

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of the `Optional<Wrapped>` enum in the Swift module?  Are you looking to emulate something like that?

Comment: @JAL Where do I look for an implementation of `Optional<Wrapped>`? Is this something for which source code is available?

Comment: I would check out [`Optional.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift) in the Swift source code, or just type `Optional` in Xcode and "Jump to declaration" to see the public module map.

Comment: Also consider the `NilLiteralConvertible` protocol.  But you get that behavior for free by just using Optionals.

Comment: @JAL Thanks for the reference! It looks like Swift's implementation relies on this functionality being understood by the compiler, because they do `if let x = self` (see line 237, 252).

Comment: Hmm, that's in `unsafelyUnwrapped`.  I wonder where the "safe" unwrap functionality is located.  Maybe where `Wrapped` is declared?  It also might not even be in the Swift layer, it might be in the SILGen/Obj-C level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift's powerful pattern matching system makes something close to this very possible. The `case let...` pattern does much of what you propose:

```
if case let x = getMyLogical() where x.boolValue {
    assert(x.boolValue) // boolValue must evaluate to true to get here
}
```

It works with `guard` statements too:

```
guard case let x = getMyLogical() where x.boolValue else { fatalError() }

assert(x.boolValue) // boolValue must evaluate to true to get here
```

In other words, the `case let...` syntax can be used to conditionally bind any value to any name for use in an `if` block or after a `guard` statement.

And I suppose for completeness, it works inside a `switch` block as well:

```
switch getMyLogical() {
case let x where x.boolValue:
    assert(x.boolValue) // boolValue must evaluate to true to get here
default:
    break
}
```

And as the logical test for a loop:

```
while case let x = getMyLogical() where x.boolValue {
    assert(x.boolValue) // boolValue must evaluate to true to get here
}
```

For a long time I thought `switch` statements were the only place you could use `case let...` But they can be used in other places, too.

I'll add one final note. The `case let...` pattern can even be used to unwrap optionals:

```
let num: Int? = 42
if case let x? = num {
    print(x)
}
```

The `if let...` syntax for unwrapping optionals appears to be a special case of the general `case let...` pattern matching syntax, an added bit of syntactic sugar to make optionals even easier to work with, but not fundamentally different than the more general `case let...` functionality.

Comment: This is even better, because the call to `x.boolValue` is made explicitly. Thanks!